# How to be sure a http request is local when using HttpListener

Tags: .net, http, httplistener, httplistenerrequest

I'm using `HttpListener`. However, I only want to process requests that come locally, not from another machine/server.

How would I programmatically verify if an incoming request is local for sure? Would I need to use some of the `HttpListenerRequest` members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with [`RemoteEndPoint` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistenerrequest.remoteendpoint.aspx) if the remote address of the request equals `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 5):

The `HttpListenerRequest` has a property [`IsLocal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistenerrequest.islocal.aspx) which should also provide this information.  However, it is returning `false` on my computer.  Reflecting into the source code, it appears that this is because the `IsLocal` property uses the code:

```cs
    return this.LocalEndPoint.Address == this.RemoteEndPoint.Address;
```

when perhaps it should use the code in the (inaccessible) `InternalIsLocal` property which is:

```cs
    return this.LocalEndPoint.Address.Equals(this.RemoteEndPoint.Address);
```

(This expression returns `true` for my situation).  Using this approach might be preferable so that your code is not dependent on an IPv4 address as the transition is made to IPv6.

Comment: Based on your text alone, it seems that `IsLocal` returns true when, e.g., you access your own machine via its external IP address, e.g. `192.168.1.130`.

Comment: Actually, I'm not certain if `IsLocal` would ever return true.  Since the `IpAddress` class does not overload the `==` operator, the `IsLocal` property is doing reference equality which likely will always return false whereas the inaccessible `InternalIsLocal` is doing value equality which should return true where appropriate.  I would assume that the value equality version would return true when accessing your machine via the external IP address.

Comment: InternalIsLocal is not accessible at least not for me. So I used req.LocalEndPoint.Address.Equals(req.RemoteEndPoint.Address where req is my HttpListenerRequest.

Comment: Correct, it is inaccessible.  I tweaked the answer to make this clearer.